# Debugger memory watch/examine for cached memory

Tags: debugging, caching, gdb, arm, ds-5

I am trying to debug a program which is partially working with cached data memory and from cached instruction memory. The question is about how the debugger works, when trying to examine such a memory. Does it access the cached copy when examining a specific location? If so, does it actually modify the cache, as it has to fetch the data once it's a miss? Does it mean that the program behavior might be different under debugger from the one without it? Any way to debug cache-related issues, without the debugger to affect the caches?
**Update:** The specific CPU core is ARM Cortex-A5. The debugger is DSTREAM/DS-5

Comment: Are you investigating problems in the cache itself (as an EE)?  Or is this a program logic problem in which you suspect the cache might be causing a problem?

Comment: It might be a wrong cache usage or a hardware bug. I hope it is the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DS-5](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0481h/index.html) uses a JTAG probe connected into the CPU.  To read the CPU's addressable memory, it has to run the CPU through its micro-operations to fetch memory.  This perturbs the cache differently than if the CPU were simply to run the program.

You can minimize the effect by not stopping the CPU until after critical (suspect) code and then try to piece together what must have happened from the contents of registers and memory.  If you can run a program from its beginning to the breakpoint, especially if that is 10,000+ instructions, the cache probably will be put into the correct state.  Unless there is asynchronous activity.

To identify whether an issue is due to caching, maybe you can simply disable the cache?

Comment: Thanks. The disabling is indeed solving the problem. this is why it is suspected.

Comment: If the SoC has a Coresight Debug Access Port or similar, then it _is_ possible to do things like read physical memory and poke peripherals without perturbing the stopped CPU. DS-5's cache awareness ought to be able to [poke about in the cache RAMs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0433c/BABEJGAD.html) non-destructively, too.

Comment: @Notlikethat Yeah, I know about these instructions, but I wonder how they affect the caches themselves. Also, unfortunately the A5 is not providing the cache awareness in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question is a bit generic because it will depend on the CPU.

However some very global rules:

- The debugger will try to see what the CPU sees on a data access, which will include cache lookups on the data cache.
- This is different for instruction cache, as the debugger will normally not do a lookup as it will perform data accesses. But this is normally not a problem as instruction cache does not contain dirty data. Depending on the debugger, it can clean DCache and invalidate corresponding ICache line if a data is written.
- Debug access will try to not be intrusive, and can force a mode in which no linefill is performed in case of miss. But this is really dependent on the CPU and not a global rule.

Comment: Can you tell anything specific about Cortex-A5?